# Passing response with coverage.js produces error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I am using coverage.js for displaying data.

When I pass my variable (in which I get coverage response) into html file as we do it for angular to display expression,i t gives syntax error:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 40px">
    <div id="jsonAnswer" class="jsonAnswer" style="display: none">
        {{coveragedetailjson}}
    </div>
</div>
```

where coveragedetailjson is my variable where I get my response as a json

```
var data = $.parseJSON($("#jsonAnswer").html());
var coverage = new Coverage(data);

buildCoverageHTML = function (coverage) {
    $(".coverage-section").remove();

    var plugin = new CoveragePlugin(coverage);

    // Adds the demographic section
    plugin.addEligibleMetadataSection();
    plugin.addDemographicsSection();
    plugin.addInsuranceSection1();
    plugin.addInsuranceSection2();
    plugin.addInsuranceSection3();
    plugin.addPlanMaximumMinimumDeductibles();
    plugin.addPlanCoinsurance();
    plugin.addPlanCopayment();
    plugin.addPlanDisclaimer();
    plugin.addAdditionalInsurancePolicies();
    plugin.addGenericServices();


    $('body').append(plugin.coverageSection);
};

buildCoverageHTML(coverage);
```

The above code in script tag

The fiddle I am using :

https://jsfiddle.net/Eligible/pqspk8gf/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=pqspk8gf

> SyntaxError : Unexpected token {

Comment: put code please

Comment: post some code what you have tried?

Comment: I have added the code @ÁlvaroTouzón

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
var data = $.parseJSON($("#jsonAnswer").html());
```

to use

```
var data = coveragedetailjson
```

instead of accessing DOM for this value.

In your case the variable  **{{coveragedetailjson}}** is not updated/replaced with your JSON data when running the code.

Comment: How this {{coveragedetailjson}} get generated?, here "{{coveragedetailjson}}" is present instead of JSON data. You can try console.log(data); before passing to Coverage and check the value.

Comment: {{coveragedetailjson}} is the variable in controller in which I get response data from an API call and for displaying it in html page I pass it as a expression as I am using angularjs.

Comment: So , you are using angularJS and accessing DOM element using Jquery. It is not a good practice at all, Try getting the data value from $scope and never try to access it from DOM.

Or try to move

var coverage = new Coverage(data);
buildCoverageHTML(coverage);
into the promise resolve/then function to get exact result.

Comment: Thanks for the tip !!